# VSCode doestn't show open editor under the command center

Tags: visual-studio-code

I don't know what I have done but I cannot see the Open Editors under the command center.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weQSN.png)

I think I made a mistake clicking on the wrong spot and I tried all the obvious things like right clicking everywhere or just clicking on the tree dot on the right of everything but I didn't found any solution.

Can anyone help?

Comment: use the `...` menu of the Explorer Bar

Comment: The problem is that the editor groups is missing.

Comment: what do you see when you use that menu

Comment: Open Editors  - Folder (not changable) - Outline - Timeline. They are all selected.

Comment: Right-click off to the right of the open tab (your `Untitled-5`).  You should see a menu with a `Tab Bar` option at the bottom.  Click that option and choose `Multiple Tabs`.

Comment: Well, the option tab bar didn't appear but I managed to solve this in the system setting --> tab bar --> show tabs.
Thanks for your support the real problem is that I didn't know what were the correct name for that section.
Thank you all!